# Best drying agent for ozone?

Tags: ozone

For cleaning purposes I do bubble ozone trough $\ce{H2O}$.

However the ozone gas is moist then, but I need it as dry as possible.

I intended to use silica gel as drying agent.

However the orange silica gel that I usually use has an organic moisture indicator included.

I think that $\ce{SiO2}$ does not react with $\ce{O3}$ itself, but I worry that the organic moisture indicator will react with the $\ce{O3}$ and form compounds that influence the following processes.

Does anyone have experience of what drying agent to use on ozone?

Is there a reason to worry about the organic moisture indicator in the $\ce{SiO2}$?

Comment: Do you really need to pass the ozone through water? You could try dry alumina?

Comment: Yes I need water for a simple reason. The feed gas of the O3 generator contains a little N2, so subsequently some NO2 is formed in the corona discharge. Water seems the best way to get rid of the NO2 while the O3 can pass on once the H2O is saturated.